# Property next does not exist

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
export function processFiles(){     

     let files = returnFiles();     
     files.next(); 
}
export function* returnFiles(){     
      for(var i=0;i<10;i++){         
            yield i;     
      } 
}
```

when trying out the generators in typescript i am getting following error

> property next doesnt exist on type IterableIterator

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version of typescript (I am using 2.4.2, and it is working), you have `"downlevelIteration": true` in your tsconfig, and added `"@types/node"` as a dev dependency.

Comment: i am getting error on returnFiles function property next not found

Comment: i solved it by targeting es6 thanks

Answer (score -3):

it works fine:

[image]

## More

Some things you can check:

- Use TypeScript latest
- Make sure you are compiling the file before running it.